# Microsoft Access SQL - Modifying date format in SELECT query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm just starting to learn SQL and am using it with a database in Microsoft Access 2013. With this database, I import a CSV weekly, then have a query to Select certain fields. One of these fields is an irregular timestamp which I have to import as a short text (Ex. Format: "2015-07-03T02:47:21+00:00").

In my Select query, I convert the Timestamp to a usable DateTime (And subtract seven hours) with this code: `FORMAT(DATEADD("h", -7, MID(PurchaseDate,1,10) + " " + MID(PurchaseDate,12,8)), "M/D/YY H:MM") AS OrderDate` When applied to the example above, this returns "7/2/15 19:47:21," which is exactly what I want.

However, the query does not recognize the result as dates and will not let me filter/sort them as dates. Is there a way to have this output in date format so that I can sort and filter by date and time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DATEADD` function should return a valid date datatype.  When you use the `FORMAT` function you are converting the date into a string.  Just do not use the format function and the expression should return as a date datatype:

```
DATEADD("h", -7, MID(PurchaseDate,1,10) + " " + MID(PurchaseDate,12,8)) AS OrderDate
```

Comment: I deleted mine, which was redundant now that you have provided some needed corrections.  V0ted up.

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I needed, I guess simpler is better here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DateValue function to convert from date strung to date type.

Comment: `DateValue` will remove the time portion, though.